# Did the patriarchs travel at night?

Tags: history, torah-study, abraham

I have heard that Abraham and the other Patriarchs would have travelled during the night and encamp during the daytime.

What evidence is there for such a claim?

Comment: There is evidence against that claim: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.45.24?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.45.24.1&lang2=en&p3=Taanit.10b&lang3=en

Comment: also evidence against https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.3